# Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name android react-native

Tags: android, react-native

Im trying to use react-native-spruce lib.

I did yarn add, linked but this is what i get when i try to react-native run-android:

```
:app:processDebugResources

C:\Users\mtlok\Desktop\pep\spruce_test\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\Users\mtlok\Desktop\pep\spruce_test\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

:app:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

In a newly created project. What could be wrong?

Comment: Please post your app/gradle